How do you share folders using key based authentication on windows 10?
I know this has already been asked here How do I share folders using key-based authentication on Windows 10? , but that was eight years ago and I hope new software that can make this possible has been created.
I'm in a situation where I want to share a folder not in domain without using user authentication and, as far as I'm aware, this is the only alternative.


Do you want to avoid OS user accounts or do you want to avoid passwords? Or both? 2) Do you specifically want SMB-based sharing (Windows network folders), or any other method?


@grawity Sorry for the delay.
I actually wanted both Users and Passwords to not be necessary, to be able to enter the folder without any visible authentication from the user whatsoever.
In the end I opted for using the "Anonymous Access" approach since I didn't want to use windows accounts as a reference, and thought that maybe a key, like in SSH, would be useful for this specific request.
